# Django: ROOT_URLCONF: How to distinguish between two folders with same name with two 'urls.py'?

Tags: python, django

`settings.py`:
[image]

From the picture, you can see that there is the path `trydjango/urls.py` and `trydjango/trydjango/urls.py`. I used the latter to import my views as the FreeCodeCamp tutorial said to do.

`ROOT_URLCONF` is set to:
`ROOT_URLCONF = 'trydjango.urls'`.

I can't go to any of my webpages in the code below for some reason.

`trydjango/trydjango/urls.py`:

[image]

I attempted to move what I had in '*trydjango/trydjango/urls.py*' to '*trydjango/urls.py*' and this still did not work. I also attempted to change **ROOT_URLCONF** to: `ROOT_URLCONF = 'trydjango.trydjango.urls'`,but this did not work either.

What should I do here? Please advise.

Comment: Why do you have a urls.py in the top folder? By default, it should just be in trydjango/trydjango/urls.py. This is what the path for ROOT_URLCONF refers to in your above screenshot. What are you seeing when you try to navigate to the configured views?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have rendered the correct templates.

Delete all the url patterns(the lines that start with `path`), except for line 27 in your code. Then, write the following code inside your `urlpatterns` list:

```
path('',include('appname.urls'))
```

Replace the `appname` with the name of your application, which I am guessing is `product`.
Then, create a new file called `urls.py` in your application. Then, write the following code in it:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *yourviews*

urlpatterns = [
   *your urlpatterns*
]
```

This is the standard procedure for creating url routes. I don't know what tutorial you are following.